# Display base64 image inside a bokeh figure

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

Let’s say I have a small red bullet base64 image:

```
im = ‘iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==’
```

To display it inside my notebook I use:

```
from IPython import display
display.HTML(f'<img src="data:image/png;base64,{im}" />')
```

Now I want to draw this base64 image inside my notebook bokeh figure.

How I should proceed, for instance, if I want to draw 5 im inside a bokeh figure randomly (see below figure). ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DSgUY image_url do the job thanks for the idea !

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
import base64
im = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
url = 'data:image/png;base64,'+im 
p = figure(x_range=(0,500), y_range=(0,500))
p.image_url( url=[url], x=300, y=300,w=100,h=100)
show(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do 2 things. Style **markers** to meet your goal or using **image_url** from figure to load an image url as you want. From the documentation of Bokeh: *The actual retrieving and loading of the images happens on the client* so I think you probably need to convert base64string to image and pass the URL. If you can do that, I generate a code below for the 2 solutions I thought about:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row, column

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# generate random floating point values
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randint


# set number of random points
N=5
seed(1)
x_values = randint(0, 10, N)
y_values = randint(0, 10, N)

offset = 2
x_min = np.amin(x_values) - offset
x_max = np.amax(x_values) + offset
y_min = np.amin(y_values) - offset
y_max = np.amax(y_values) + offset


# Solution 1: style circle marker to achive what you want
p1 = figure(x_range=(x_min, x_max), y_range=(y_min, y_max))
p1.circle(x_values, y_values, color='red', size=30, alpha=0.8)
p1.xaxis.visible = False
p1.yaxis.visible = False
p1.xgrid.visible = False
p1.ygrid.visible = False


# Solution 2: using image_url
image_url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Red_Circle%28small%29.svg"
p2 = figure(x_range=(x_min, x_max), y_range=(y_min, y_max))

for index in range(len(x_values)):
    p2.image_url(url=[image_url], x = x_values[index], y = y_values[index], anchor="center")

p2.xaxis.visible = False
p2.yaxis.visible = False
p2.xgrid.visible = False
p2.ygrid.visible = False

# Display the plot
output_file('example.html')
layout = row(p1,p2)
show(layout)
```

Check this out:
[bokeh.plotting.Figure.image_url](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html?highlight=figure#bokeh.plotting.Figure.image_url)

Also:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/image_url.html

Build-in Markers:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html

If you have that base64string in a txt file like *"image-base64-string.txt"* and you want as output a *'red-circle.png'* image file you can use:

```
import base64
    with open("image-base64-string.txt", 'r') as base64_img :
        base64_img_bytes = base64_img.encode('utf-8')
    
        with open('red-circle.png', 'wb') as image_png:
            image_png.write(base64.decodebytes(base64_img_bytes))
```